# PostGIS: Create bounding from geometry

Tags: postgis, extents

I have 4 vertices and I need to get the bounding box something like the one in the image below. 
A, B, C and D are the vertices.

The red area is the one which I need to eliminate while I only need to retain the green area.

Maybe, I would need ST_Intersects, but I'm not sure how do I go about using this for the mentioned use.

**NOTE** I will need the points A, B, C and D as part of the green area, I do not want to eliminate them, I only need to get rid of the center part which is in red.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I will assume, the green box is a full box and you want to clip out an area based on four input coordinates. You just need to create a polygon from the points and run a difference.

So:

```
SELECT ST_Difference(green.geom, (
ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(
ST_MakePoint(a.x_coord, a.y_coord),
ST_MakePoint(b.x_coord, b.y_coord),
ST_MakePoint(c.x_coord, c.y_coord),
ST_MakePoint(d.x_coord, d.y_coord),
ST_MakePoint(a.x_coord, a.y_coord),
))
)) from green
```

It could be simplified depending how your data is stored.

*.*_coord should be the coordinate itself, so in a numeric format.

Comment: it is good practice to wrap the st_difference function in the coalesce function in case there is null values in one of the geometries. but your query should be fine for this example